# How to change the hover color on multiple pieces of text when you click on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's the page that I'm having the issue on - http://impdigitaldev.site/home-v2-services-test/

Just scroll down a bit to the services section to see the menu that I'm referring to with this question.

So...

I've got a kind of "menu" on the services section of that page that has 4 different selections. When you click on one of the menu items, the background changes to orange.

When an item in the menu isn't selected however, the text should have a hover that changes the text orange. It currently has that.

The challenge I'm running into is that when you select a menu item, the background changes to orange. With the text hover still being set to orange - that creates a bit of a problem.

**What I would like to have happen is that when you select a menu item, it removes the hover effect on that particular text element (or at least sets it to white), while maintaining the hover effect on the other 3 menu items on the page.**

**Then when you click on the other menu items, it does the same to the text in those divs, and kind of "resets" the hover on the previous menu item back to the orange hover on the text.**

I've had some success with removing the hover effect when you click on a div, but I've not figured out resetting the hover effect back to the regular orange hover when you click on another div.

I dropped a snippet of the code I was experimenting with before that did change the hover color to white on the active menu item, but it doesn't switch back to orange after you select the other menu items.

Each button (div) of the menu has the class .blurb-1, 2, 3, 4 respectively.

(please be gentle, I literally just started experimenting with java/jquery like 2 weeks ago haha, so this code is probably garbage)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".blurb-1").click(function() {
      $('.blurb-1:hover').css('color', '#ffffff');
      $('.blurb-2:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
      $('.blurb-3:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
      $('.blurb-4:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
    });

    $(".blurb-2").click(function() {
      $('.blurb-1:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
      $('.blurb-2:hover').css('color', '#ffffff');
      $('.blurb-3:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
      $('.blurb-4:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
    });

    $(".blurb-3").click(function() {
      $('.blurb-1:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
      $('.blurb-2:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
      $('.blurb-3:hover').css('color', '#ffffff');
      $('.blurb-4:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
    });

    $(".blurb-4").click(function() {
      $('.blurb-1:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
      $('.blurb-2:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
      $('.blurb-3:hover').css('color', '#ff6900');
      $('.blurb-4:hover').css('color', '#ffffff');
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Welcome on SO ! Firstly I suggest you make a snippet or jsfiddle. Also, this code works fine ? I suggest you to clean the question to be more focus on the problem and not explain everything that is coming in your page

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. Simplify your HTML structure and your JS code. Utilize stylesheet classes to make the hover changes you want... this example only does buttons one and two.

```js
$(".blurb").click(function() {
      $("body").removeClass(["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"]);
      $("body").addClass($(this).data('class'));
    })
```

```css
body.b1 [data-class=b1]:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
body.b1 [data-class=b2]:hover {
  color: green;
}
body.b1 [data-class=b3]:hover {
  color: red;
}
body.b1 [data-class=b4]:hover {
  color: blue;
}
body.b2 [data-class=b1]:hover {
  color: indigo;
}
body.b2 [data-class=b2]:hover {
  color: orange;
}
body.b2 [data-class=b3]:hover {
  color: brown;
}
body.b2 [data-class=b4]:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-class='b1' class='blurb'>Blurb 1</button>
<button data-class='b2' class='blurb'>Blurb 2</button>
<button data-class='b3' class='blurb'>Blurb 3</button>
<button data-class='b4' class='blurb'>Blurb 4</button>
```